# Business required lookup set by javascript error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I´m working on a javascript event in dynamics crm 2013.

I have an option set (let´s call it fieldA). When it changes, I want to set the value of a lookup (let´s call it fieldB). This lookup is mandatory (or business required as CRM calls it).

Here is my code:

```
function fieldAOnChange() {

    /* computation of field B value: entityId, name, entityType */

    var lookupField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldBId);
    if (!isUndefined(lookupField)) {
        if (entityId != null && name != null && entityType != null) {
            var lookupValue = new Array();
            lookupValue[0] = new Object();
            lookupValue[0].id = entityId;
            lookupValue[0].name = name;
            lookupValue[0].entityType = entityType;
            lookupField.setValue(lookupValue);
        } else {
            lookupField.setValue(null);
        }

        lookupField.fireOnChange();
    }
}
```

This code works **almost** fine. The lookup is correctly filled, however the icon "this is a mandatory field and it´s not filled" appears next to the field. **This is what I´m trying to fix !**

If I click on the field to get the focus and then elsewhere to lose it, the icon disappear. If I change again the value in the option set and the fieldB is updated again, the icon disappear also.

I have tried stupid things like setting the focus on and off or launching the fireOnChange event twice without results.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I don´t think it was stupid to let the focus go elsewhere, although, did you made sure the focus was at first instance in the fieldB ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to emulate with code what was making the icon disappear. So I set the focus on fieldB and then elsewhere. I called it stupid because I would prefer the expected result: the field is set, there is no reason for this icon to appear...

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem is, maybe a little work around, could be changing the required level of the field once you set it to a value or null:

Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setRequiredLevel("required");
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setRequiredLevel("none");